# How do I validate a textbox based on a drop down/ radio button

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010, validation, drop-down-menu

I am creating a page with optional drop down. If the user selects nothing, the text box is not required, if they do, it is. How do I do that?

(Optional drop down) -> Relative - Mother/Father/None

(Text box is required if user select 'Mother or Father')

Answer (score 1):

for above answer, dont forgot to assign AutoPostback=True property to your dropdown else you will not see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable your textbox by default.

Then when the user selects from the dropdown, enable the textbox.

As part of your validation you can check if the textbox is disabled, if it isn't then validate it.

The textbox becoming enabled can also act as a visual reference to the user that input is now required.

The don't really need to be related to each other as such.